# Time-Driven Trigger additional parameters

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a Google Sheets addon that calls a specific function at a user specified time using time-driven triggers. I'd like to have each trigger pass a set of parameters specific to that trigger to this function. For instance

- trigger[1] passes {animal: bat, color: blue} to the function
- trigger[2] passes {animal: cat, color: red} to the function

Is there any way to do such a thing?

Originally I had intended to store these parameters in a hidden spreadsheet and mark them each by the triggers uniqueId but it doesn't seem like the event handler for time-driven triggers carries the triggers uniqueId with it.

Comment: Maybe you could store the trigger ID in the User Properties.  When the trigger is created, get the ID, then store the ID in the User Properties.  If you want the trigger ID of the trigger that runs everyday at noon, store it with the property name 'noon':'trigger_ID_here'

Comment: I suppose, since an add-on can only run one time-driven trigger per hour, I could use the hour as a unique identifier instead of the trigger's uniqueId. It still seems a bit patched together rather than being able to reference values by the actual trigger Id. But I think I would use the hidden spreadsheet approach rather than user or script properties.

Comment: If you've got a small-ish number of unique triggers, each could call a separate trigger function that then invokes your target function with the required parameters.